# Watch Pull Request comments in a desktop client

Tags: github, bitbucket, pull-request

I asked myself several times howto enhance the pull-request comment/answer+change code process. We are using bitbucket as git server frontend. When a user make comments in a pull request, he/she is commenting source code changes in the web gui of bitbucket.

Now the uncomfortable process comes in: When a user is reacting on the comments (e.g. by changing the code concerning to the comments), he allways needs to switch between the web gui of  bitbucket and a text editor in order to apply the changes in code. "A lot" of time is used to find the correct location (especially when the line numbers are shifted because of inserts/deletes above in the file).

Question: **Is there any desktop client** (me I am interested in a window client) that supports pull request and **displays the comments in an editable local file copy?** I mean like in a diff viewer (K3Diff, TortoiseDiff, ...) where you see diffs (or in my case the pull request comments) and can make changes direct on the local working copy next the comments of the pull request?

Comment: A possible solution could be SmartGit  http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/review but I didn't have used it in that way though. They also support Bitbucket Server.

Comment: Looks promising. Bitbucket comments are displayed inline BUT the file with the inline comments is read only.